# Merge sort code in Python using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, mergesort

Below is intended for a merge sort written in Python. It is throwing an error "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded". Please let me know if I am missing the logic to end the recursion.

```
  list=[]
  list1=[]
  list2=[]
  def merge(list,list1,list2):

  for k in range(1,len(list1)+len(list2)):
    i=1
    j=1
    if list1[i]>list2[j]:
        list[k]=list2[j]
        j=+1
        k=+1
    else:
        list[k]=list2[i]
        i=+1
        k=+1


    def split(list,list1,list2):
if len(list)<>1:
    list1=list[:len(list)/2]
    list2=list[len(list)/2:]
return  


   def sort(list):
      split(list,list1,list2)
      sort(list1)
      sort(list2)
      merge(list,list1,list2)


      list = [15,8,59,69,45,23]
      sort(list)
```

Comment: Don't name objects `list` or `sort`. They're built in and you're shadowing them (meaning you can't use the built in anymore because it's overwritten). And it's hard for the rest of us to follow

Comment: @mhlester: `sort` is okay. It's a method. It's `sorted` that causes problems if you shadow it.

Comment: sorry of course you're right. i just dislike such a bland name

Comment: Not sure if it's just from moving code to SO, but your formatting is wonky. It definitely can't hurt to get your formatting all straightened out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this program:

```
 def sort( aList ):
      aList = _mergesort( aList, 0, len( aList ) - 1 )
      return aList

def _mergesort( aList, first, last ):
  mid = ( first + last ) / 2
  if first < last:
    _mergesort( aList, first, mid )
    _mergesort( aList, mid + 1, last )

  a, f, l = 0, first, mid + 1
  tmp = [None] * ( last - first + 1 )

  while f <= mid and l <= last:
    if aList[f] < aList[l] :
      tmp[a] = aList[f]
      f += 1
    else:
      tmp[a] = aList[l]
      l += 1
    a += 1

  if f <= mid :
    tmp[a:] = aList[f:mid + 1]

  if l <= last:
    tmp[a:] = aList[l:last + 1]

  a = 0
  while first <= last:
    aList[first] = tmp[a]
    first += 1
    a += 1
  return aList

aList = [15,8,59,69,45,23]
print sort(aList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid global variable initialization in this script

```
>>> x = 5
>>> def show2():
...     x = 42
...     print x
... 
>>> show2()
42
>>> x
5
```

The problem is that you recursively call yourself with the same parameters, which guarantees infinite recursion. It doesn't matter how high you set the recursion limit; you can't set it past infinity.*

Comment: Yes. Got the point. But how can I use variables without defining them? I am a beginner in Python. I am posting the partial new code and                                                          
           def split(seq,seq1,seq2):
    seq1=seq[:len(seq)/2]
    seq2=seq[len(seq)/2:]
    print seq,seq1,seq2
    return                                                          
             OUTPUT: [15, 8, 59, 69, 45, 23] [15, 8, 59] [69, 45, 23]
             [] [] []
[] [] []
[] [] []

Comment: OK i added new program of merge sort. Hope it will helpfull.